# Avoid a second of blank page using Pre-Bootstrap Loading Screen For Angular2

Tags: angular, animation, lazy-loading, angular2-routing

I'm animating pre-bootstrap loading in Angular 2 like this:

```
<app-root>
  <div class="background">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="loading-ball">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</app-root>
```

but when I added a lazy loading module functionality I started seeing a 1 second blank page between the animation and the final page

Probably that was cause because I finish loading the app-root component before load the final module.

What is the way to avoid this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happen because the your app-component load the lazy component from the server so it takes some time in this it shows the blank screen.
You can avoid this by importing the code in the `app-component.html`.

```
<div class="background" *ngIf="loading">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="loading-ball">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

This should be overlay all the screen and in app.component.ts

```
  constructor(
      private _router: Router
  ) { }
  loading = false;

  ngOnInit() {
      this._router.events.subscribe(v => this.navigationInterceptor(v));
  }

  navigationInterceptor(event: RouterEvent): void {
      if (event instanceof NavigationStart) {
          this.loading = true;
      }
      if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
          this.loading = false;
      }
      if (event instanceof NavigationCancel) {
          this.loading = false;
      }
      if (event instanceof NavigationError) {
          this.loading = false;
      }
  }
```

Comment: In order to make it work for me, I had to change the code inside ngOnInit by this (because Event type doesn't cast automatically to RouterEvent):  var app = this;
  this.router.events.subscribe(function(v:RouterEvent) {app.navigationInterceptor(v)});